# Problems with SQL Inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having some problems while trying to optimize my SQL.

I got 2 tables like this:

```
Names
id, analyseid, name

Analyses
id, date, analyseid.
```

I want to get the newest analyse from Analyses (ordered by date) for every name (they are unique) in Names. I can't really see how to do this without using 2 x nested selects.

My try (Dont get confused about the names. It's the same principle):

```
SELECT
 B.id,
 B.chosendatetime,
 vStockNames.name
FROM
 vStockNames
INNER JOIN
 (
 SELECT TOP 1
  vAnalysesHistory.id,
  vAnalysesHistory.chosendatetime,
  vAnalysesHistory.companyid
 FROM
  vAnalysesHistory
 ORDER BY
  vAnalysesHistory.chosendatetime DESC
 ) AS B
ON
 B.companyid = vStockNames.stockid
```

In my example the problem is that i only get 1 row returned (because of top 1). But if I exclude this, I can get multiple analyses of the same name.

Can you help me ? - THanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: In future, choose one set of table names, and matching column names, and make your question self-consistent.  Don't switch names part way through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2000+:

```
 SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 
                a.id
           FROM vAnalysesHistory AS a 
          WHERE a.companyid = n.stockid 
       ORDER BY a.chosendatetime DESC) AS id,
        n.name, 
        (SELECT TOP 1 
                a.chosendatetime 
           FROM vAnalysesHistory AS a 
          WHERE a.companyid = n.stockid 
       ORDER BY a.chosendatetime DESC) AS chosendatetime
   FROM vStockNames AS n
```

SQL Server 2005+, using CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT a.id,
          a.date,
          a.analyseid,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.analyseid
                                ORDER BY a.date DESC) AS rk
     FROM ANALYSES a)
SELECT n.id, 
       n.name,
       c.date
  FROM NAMES n
  JOIN cte c ON c.analyseid = n.analyseid
            AND c.rk = 1
```

...without CTE:

```
SELECT n.id, 
       n.name,
       c.date
  FROM NAMES n
  JOIN (SELECT a.id,
               a.date, 
               a.analyseid,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.analyseid
                                     ORDER BY a.date DESC) AS rk
          FROM ANALYSES a) c ON c.analyseid = n.analyseid
                            AND c.rk = 1
```

Comment: Returning: The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.

Comment: @s0mmer: That means you're either using SQL Server 2000 or prior, or the Compact Edition

Comment: @s0mmer check `compatibility level` in right click on database -> properties -> options

Comment: @s0mmer: The Express Edition supports analytic functions; the Compact Edition is an embeddable version that lacks the functionality of the other Editions.

Comment: compatibility level says sql 2000. So.. not possible then?

Comment: @s0mmer: I updated with a SS2000 safe version of the query.  I support a 2005 instance with databases set to 2000 compatibility, and I don't get the issue with using analytic functions...

Comment: I converted it to my tables:
SELECT     id, name,
                          (SELECT     TOP 1 chosendatetime
                            FROM          vAnalysesHistory AS a
                            WHERE      (companyid = n.stockid)
                            ORDER BY chosendatetime DESC) AS Expr1
FROM         vStockNames AS n

only problem is that im getting id fra vStockNames (Names) and now vAnalysesHistory (Analyses)..

Comment: @s0mmer: Given the limitations, you'll need two subqueries - see the update.

Comment: ... one last question ! in vAnalysesHistory there is a attribute called analysetype. What if i want to get only analyses where analysetype = 3 ?

Comment: @s0mmer: You can add that to the WHERE clause in each subquery, but that means you very likely will get `name` values with NULL for `id` and `chosendatetime`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Im getting NULL as you say. No i want to exclude those with NULL's.

Answer (score 1):

You're only asking for the TOP 1, so that's all you're getting. If you want one per companyId, you need to specify that in the SELECT on vAnalysesHistory. Of course, JOINs must be constant and do not allow this. Fortunately, CROSS APPLY comes to the rescue in cases like this.

```
SELECT
 B.id,
 B.chosendatetime,
 vStockNames.name
FROM
 vStockNames
CROSS APPLY
 (
 SELECT TOP 1
  vAnalysesHistory.id,
  vAnalysesHistory.chosendatetime,
  vAnalysesHistory.companyid
 FROM
  vAnalysesHistory
 WHERE companyid = vStockNames.stockid
 ORDER BY
  vAnalysesHistory.chosendatetime DESC
 ) AS B
```

You could also use ROW_NUMBER() to do the same:

```
SELECT
 B.id,
 B.chosendatetime,
 vStockNames.name
FROM
 vStockNames
INNER JOIN
 (
 SELECT
  vAnalysesHistory.id,
  vAnalysesHistory.chosendatetime,
  vAnalysesHistory.companyid,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY companyid ORDER BY chosendatetime DESC) AS row
 FROM
  vAnalysesHistory
 ) AS B
ON
 B.companyid = vStockNames.stockid AND b.row = 1
```

Personally I'm a fan of the first approach. It will likely be faster and is easier to read IMO.

Comment: Returning: 'APPLY relational operator' support not available in this server version.
The CROSS APPLY SQL construct or statement is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work for you?

```
;with RankedAnalysesHistory as 
(
 SELECT 
  vah.id,
  vah.chosendatetime,
  vah.companyid
  ,rank() over (partition by vah.companyid order by vah.chosendatetime desc) rnk
 FROM
  vAnalysesHistory vah
)
SELECT
 B.id,
 B.chosendatetime,
 vsn.name
FROM
 vStockNames vsn
 join RankedAnalysesHistory as rah on rah.companyid = vsn.stockid and vah.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you only need SQL-92 for this.  Of course, explicit documentation of the joining columns between the tables would help.

#### Simple names

```
SELECT B.ID, C.ChosenDate, N.Name
  FROM (SELECT A.AnalyseID, MAX(A.Date) AS ChosenDate
          FROM Analyses AS A
         GROUP BY A.AnalyseID) AS C
  JOIN Analyses AS B ON C.AnalyseID = B.AnalyseID AND C.ChosenDate = B.Date
  JOIN Names    AS N ON N.AnalyseID = C.AnalyseID
```

The sub-select generates the latest analysis for each company; the join with Analyses picks up the `Analyse.ID` value corresponding to that latest analysis, and the join with Names picks up the company name.  (The `C.ChosenDate` in the select-list could be replaced by `B.Date AS ChosenDate`, of course.)

#### Complicated names

```
SELECT B.ID, C.ChosenDateTime, N.Name
  FROM (SELECT A.CompanyID, MAX(A.ChosenDateTime) AS ChosenDateTime
          FROM vAnalysesHistory AS A
         GROUP BY A.CompanyID) AS C
  JOIN vAnalysesHistory AS B ON C.CompanyID      = B.CompanyID
                            AND C.ChosenDateTime = B.ChosenDateTime
  JOIN vStockNames AS N ON N.AnalyseID = C.AnalyseID
```

Same query with systematic renaming (and slightly different layout to avoid horizontal scrollbars).

Comment: This works also.. What if i want to get only rows from Analyses where analysetype = 3?

Comment: Got it not: SELECT     B.id, C.ChosenDateTime, N.name
FROM         (SELECT     companyid, MAX(chosendatetime) AS ChosenDateTime
                       FROM          vAnalysesHistory AS A
                       WHERE      (analyseid = 3)
                       GROUP BY companyid) AS C INNER JOIN
                      vAnalysesHistory AS B ON C.companyid = B.companyid AND C.ChosenDateTime = B.chosendatetime AND B.analyseid = 3 INNER JOIN
                      vStockNames AS N ON N.stockid = C.companyid
ORDER BY N.name.. Thanks very much!